# How to add specific, not released yet commit to Rails current release?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I would like to add this change https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/94584c2510743a45d9030d1b94dd33a074518b17 to release/version 6.0.3.3. How I can do this? Is it smart idea to do so? It sounds for me like I would like to cherry pick this change?

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows:

1. Create `rails` fork of the unreleased version that you need
2. In your *Gemfile*, add `gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/you/your-rails-fork'`
3. Run `bundle`
4. When it is released, restore `gem 'rails'` in your *Gemfile*

It is not a bad idea to do so, as long as:

1. It actually gets released at some point and you get back to the community-kept official version when it does (for the security reasons mostly).
2. You don't introduce any custom changes in the forked repository - if you do, you might get in trouble when trying to get back to official rails.

Comment: I still wonder how to add this specific commit to the current released version and check possible conflicts if any present?

Comment: As you said, `cherry-pick` is one way to go - create the latest released fork, pick the commit you want, and point to the fork in your _Gemfile_.